# Vue.js unit testing best practice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3, vue-test-utils

It's a general question. but i am curious to ask: there are many packages for vue js unit testing.

- [Vue Test Utils](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils)
- [Vue Jest](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/tree/jest-vue)
- [Vue Cypress](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-vue-unit-test)

which one would be best practice or recommended for enterprise project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not comparable, as each of them serve a different purpose.

From documentation of each of these libraries:

[vue-test-utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/)

> Vue Test Utils is the official unit testing utility library for Vue.js.

[vue-jest](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-single-file-components-with-jest.html#processing-single-file-components-in-jest)

> ... To teach Jest how to process *.vue files, we will need to install and configure the vue-jest preprocessor.

[cypress-vue-unit-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-vue-unit-test)

> A little helper to unit test Vue components in the open source Cypress.io E2E test runner

If you have no preference and looking for a place to start, then definitely start with official documentation: [Choosing a test runner](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/choosing-a-test-runner.html#choosing-a-test-runner)